# How to readout Data from a formular?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing an exercise for school. Task is to readout Data from a formular. Though I do not know much and I am stuck with the first Task. The result of the first task should be: "Your name has .... Characters." So basically if I enter a name in the text field and press the submit button it should give me the `.length` of the Name.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input id="Name" type="text" name="Name">
<input id="Ausgabe" type="submit" value="Ausgabe" onclick="ausgabe"()>
                <p id="yournamehas" class="ptags">Your Name has:</p>
                <p id="lname" class="ptags"></p>
                <p id="Characters" class="ptags"> Characters</p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function namelength() {
         var Namee = document.getElementById('#Name').value.length
         document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML = Namee
};

function ausgabe() {
    $("#Ausgabe").on("click",function(){
        {
            document.getElementById("#Ausgabe").innerHTML =
                namelength();
        }              
    })
};
```

I seriously dont know whats wrong. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: do you ever call your function ausgabe?

Comment: @fawee sorry i forgot to put it itno the question.

Comment: and your function namelength doesnt return anything

Comment: well it only returns something if you write something in the textfield

Comment: innerHTML of input#Ausgabe is undefined: document.getElementById("#Ausgabe").innerHTML =
                namelength(); because it doesnt return anything

Comment: cool still got no idea what to change to make it work

Comment: oke its ('#lname') still doesen't work though

Comment: you call getElementById so you dont need the "#" in the parenthesis

Comment: i would recommend to check out the MDN site about forms, it is a good way to get started here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('Name');
function ausGabe(){
var  b  = a.value;
var name = document.getElementById('yournamehas').innerHTML = "Your Name has:" + " " +b;
var len = document.getElementById('Characters').innerHTML = "Characters" + " " + b.length;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="Name" type="text" name="Name">
<input id="Ausgabe" type="button" value="Ausgabe" onclick="ausGabe()">
                <p id="yournamehas" class="ptags">Your Name has:</p>
                <p id="lname" class="ptags"></p>
                <p id="Characters" class="ptags"> Characters</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is a school exercise, some pointers may be useful, to go along with the other answer which is a working solution...

### jQuery vs Vanilla JS

You are using jQuery, which is a JavaScript library (a reusable bit of code) to make some jobs easier, especially regarding manipulation of elements in the browser (DOM elements). Way back, jQuery also did a more important job of 'normalising' the different browsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Netscape, etc.) before they adhered to the standards.

Nowadays jQuery is less vital as a normaliser, but still very handy for selecting elements and changing the styling, content, and handling events.

In your example you are doing some things the basic "[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)" way and some with jQuery. In a few places you have got things a bit mixed up and tried doing it a mix of ways, which won't work...

### Referencing an element

#### by id

If you have an element such as `<div id="myDiv"></div>` then you can access it using Vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv");
```

or jQuery:

```
$("#myDiv");
```

Notice that you only provide the real id with getElementById, no hash.

#### by CSS selector

Another thing that jQuery did, which was amazing at the time, was that it allowed you to access DOM elements using the same selectors as CSS. That is why the jQuery version has a hash (#) because that is the CSS selector for "id=". Nowadays there is a Vanilla JS version of that which is widely supported:

```
document.querySelector("#myDiv"); // returns a single element
document.querySelectorAll("div"); // returns multiple div elements
```

### Event handling

#### with jQuery

In your example you have used jQuery to attach some code to the click event of your button.

```
$("#Ausgabe").on("click",function(){
    // blah
});
```

That's great and attaches your function to be run later when the button is clicked.

#### with element attributes (the bad way)

However, you have put that in another function which is explicitly called when you click the button, using the old-fashioned `onclick` attribute.

```
<input id="Ausgabe" ... onclick="ausgabe()">
```

Your jQuery event is not initially attached. It only becomes so when the onclick attribute handles the first click. So you have to click the button to attach an event handler to deal with clicking the button. Have you seen the film [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)? You need to make your mind up about which approach to take. You should *definitely* be attaching to the event rather than using onclick.

#### Vanilla JS

However, you can also do that with Vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("Ausgabe").addEventListener("click", function() { /* your code goes here */ });
```

### Setting content

#### Vanilla JS

You have used the Vanilla JS approach for setting content of your element, which is great:

```
document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML = Namee;
```

#### jQuery

But that's another thing that jQuery provides a method for:

```
$("#lname").html(Namee);
```

### Be consistent

#### Vanilla JS vs jQuery

To make it easier to both write and read your code, it is better to be consistent. Decide if you are going to use Vanilla JS or jQuery and then stick to it. Although you might use jQuery for some of the more difficult things even when using Vanilla JS (like adding or [removing a CSS class](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) name).

#### Semi-colons

JavaScript instructions are *supposed* to end with a semi-colon;

You don't always have to do it, and there are people who claim that you shouldn't unless absolutely necessary. But it does make code clearer to read because JavaScript is allowed to split across multiple lines. So the semi-colon tells your reader that you've finished the instruction. My advice is to always use them.

#### Quotes

JavaScript is flexible on the use of 'single' and "double" quotes. There are different opinions on this, and plenty of arguments for/against each, but it really doesn't matter which. However it is nicer if you stick to one approach:

```
var string1 = "Stick to one set of quotes";
var string2 = 'else your code will look weird';
var string3 = `even this is allowed in modern JS`;
var string4 = "But this one is BROKEN';
```

### form submit buttons

One more thing, which also harkens back to 'the old days'...

When the [world wide web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web) was new there was no JavaScript and web pages were just a little better than plain text. The only interaction was by filling in a form and 'submitting' it back to the server.

If you have a `<form>` element which contains an `<input type="submit">` button then that's what the browser expects to do. If you press that button it will submit the form. Nowadays that's actually quite rare!

If you use that arrangement then you might find that your page doesn't act the way you expect. Therefore it is safer to use non-submit buttons which don't have any special behaviour:

```
<input type="button" value="My non-submit button">
```

### Good luck and enjoy

That's a lot of advice. Hopefully you can now see where you were going wrong before and have a better understanding of things.

I hope you enjoy coding. It's not scary and if you get properly good at it then you can have a good job in the future. But only go down that route if it really appeals to you. It's actually a horrible job if you spend most of your time on StackOverflow asking for help! ;)

### TL;DR

If that was too long and you didn't want to read it then I advise you to not become a developer. Going into the details of how things work is a very important lesson that you *never* stop learning.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. About a year a go I once did the sololearn courses for js and jquery. I quess now i mixed it up a little bit. I am probably going to stick with vanilla js in the future.

Comment: Vanilla JS is a good intention. You learn the standards that way. But jQuery will let you develop faster (e.g. [method chaining](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/#chaining)) and in ways that seem magical (e.g. [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)). When you are in control of the little stuff then you can build the big stuff. Enjoy